# iOS Heavy image switching

Tags: ios, performance, animation

I'm developing a app that will showcase products. One of the features of this app is that you will be able to "rotate" the product, using your finger/Pan-Gesture.

I was thinking in implementing this by taking photos of the product from different angles so when you "drag" the image, all I would have to do is switch the image according. If you drag a little, i switch only 1 image... if you drag a lot, i will switch them in cadence making it look like a movie... but i have a concerns and a probable solution:

- Is this "performatic"? Since its a art/museum product showcase, the photos will be quite large in size/definition, and loading/switching when "dragged a lot" might be a problem because it would cause "flickering"... And the solution would be: instead of loading pic-by-pic i would put them all inside one massive sheet, and work through them as if they were a sprite...

Is that a good ideia? Or should I stick with the pic-by-pic rotation?

**Edit 1:** There`s a complicator: the user will be able to zoom in/out and to rotate the product in any axis (X, Y and Z)...

Comment: Hi, @Leonardo I think it's worth it to put a little bounty on this. Just a Suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

My personal opinion, I don't think this will work the way you hope or the performance and/or aesthetics will not be what you want.

1) Taking individuals shots that you then try to keyframe to based on touch events won't work well because you will have inevitable inconsistencies in 'framing' the shots such that the playback won't be smooth

2) The best way to do this, I suspect, will be to shoot it with video and shoot it with some sort of rig that allows you to keep the camera fixed while rotating the object

3) I'm pretty sure this is how most 'professional' grade product carousel type presentations work

4) Even then you will have more image frames than you need -- not sure whether you plan to embed the images files in app or download on demand -- but that is also a consideration in terms of how much downsampling you'll need to do to reduce frames/file size

### Suggestion

Look at shooting these as video (somewhat like described above) and downsampling and removing excess frames using a video editor. Then you could use AVFoundation for playback and use your gestures to 'scrub' into the video frames.  I worked on something like this for HTML playback at a large company and I can assure you it was done with video.

Alternatively, if video won't work for you. Your sprite sheet solution might work (consider using SpriteKit).  But then keep in mind what I said about trying to keyframe one off camera shots together -- it just won't work well.   Maybe a compromise would be to shoot static images but do so by fixing the camera and rotating the objects at very specific increments.  That could work as well I suppose but you will  need to be very careful about light and other atmospehrics.  It doesn't take much variation at all to be detectable to the human eye causing the whole presentation to seem strange.  Good luck.

Comment: interesting... very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

A coder from my company did something like this before using 360 images of an object and it worked just great but it didn't have zoom. Maybe you could add zoom by adding a pinch gesture recognizer and placing the image view into a scroll view to zoom in on the static image.

This scenario sounds like what you really need is a simple 3D model loader library or write it in OpenGL yourself. But this pan and zoom behavior is really basic when you make that jump to 3D so it should be easy to find lots of examples.

All depends on your situation and time constraints :)

Comment: 3D model is out of question because its fine-art/museum items... this option was exhausted before... real-world implications means a few-thousands of 3d models and dependance of 3d artists to include new content... Studio/Photographers are way more abundant...